# I am trying to use ng2-file-upload in my project. But , am unable to integrate the packge into my UI.

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, ngx-bootstrap, ng2-file-upload

I am developing a website in Angular 6 and want to use [ng2-file-upload](https://valor-software.com/ng2-file-upload/) in my project. I have done everything according to the instructions in the link. Still am getting error in the UI.
The error is

> compiler.js:486 Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'MyRandomComponent' declared by the module 'AppModule'.
>
> Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.
>       at syntaxError (compiler.js:486)
>       at eval (compiler.js:15296)
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:15278)
>       at JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:34413)
>       at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:34374)
>       at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.js:34268)
>       at CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync (platform-browser-dynamic.js:239)
>       at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (core.js:5578)
>       at eval (main.ts:11)

Can anyone suggest me where am i wrong. If any other file-upload package would be better to use.
Along with answer a working demo in jsfiddle or similar would be great for reference.
I want to make the file uplaod UI, like in [image: this link]

Comment: can you paste your code for reference

Comment: It seems that your package does not support Angular 6 (ng2 refers to Angular2). You probably will have to find another one

Comment: @MBalajivaishnav i have added codes exactly as given in the link(in my question)